# Does anyone have a sample GWT 2.7.0 Maven Eclipse IDE project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gwt, gwt-2.7

I am trying to use **GWT 2.7.0.** with **Maven** and **Eclipse IDE** Does anyone have a small template?

I am particularly looking for clean project that will work with **Eclipse IDE**.

I was trying to do it on my own, but unfortunately I am failing.

[Here is my project](https://github.com/masterdany88/gwt_2.7.0_maven_eclipse). It work great with maven in linux console. I can compile and run it.

Unfortunately in **Eclipse IDE** (as maven project) it doesn't work completely.

If someone have simple project and work with it in **Eclipse IDE**, please share with me.

All this set up makes me hate GWT.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use the [tbroyer's maven archetypes](https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes) to generate a gwt project template and later do `mvn eclipse:eclipse` on every directory to import then.

Comment: I've asked about **Eclipse IDE** project. Each **Eclipse IDE** project must have `.project` file. Recomended by You `tbroyer's maven archetypes` project is not an **Eclipse IDE** one.

Comment: Create your project, for instance: `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/ -DarchetypeGroupId=net.ltgt.gwt.archetypes    -DarchetypeArtifactId=modular-webapp  -DarchetypeVersion=1.0-SNAPSHOT` and later do `mvn eclipse:eclipse` to generate the .project.

Comment: To clarify: the archetype generates in one command the three projects (client, shared, serverd) that is mentioned in [your multi-module question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32248650/does-gwt-2-7-maven-project-must-be-multi-moduled), that is just a good practice to organize your gwt code. In each directory (client, shared and server) you should do `mvn eclipse:eclipse` and import the project in eclipse. As a sample [a small project](https://github.com/comunes/gwt-initials-avatars) that I maintain generated with this archetype, and developed using Eclipse (check the tbroyer profile).

Comment: Ok. What You write make sens. But none of this project work in Eclipse for me out of the box. `mvn eclipse:eclipse` is really usefull for this. Thanks. Try to edit Your answer, that I could undone my downvote.

Comment: ["In short, Archetype is a Maven project templating toolkit"](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html)...